# Setting value to hidden fields not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an application that I am creating with Visual Studio 2013 and I'm running into some issues with assigning a value to a hidden field using jQuery. First let me say that I am assigning a value to a hidden variable because I cannot access the text value of a label in the `.cs` file directly so I have to assign the value of the label to the hidden input field so I can access it in the `.cs` file. I  hope that makes sense.

Here are the hidden input fields that I have in my `.aspx` file:

```
  <input type="hidden" id="at" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="wt" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="att" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="wtt" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="gt" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="ah" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="wh" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="th" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="tah" runat="server" />
  <input type="hidden" id="twh" runat="server" />
```

Here is the function that I run any time a key is pressed:

```
<script src="Scripts/add-bid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type=text]').keyup(function () {
                calculateTotal();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Here is the code inside of the `add-bid.js` script, namely the `calculateTotal` function:

```
$("#at").val("100");
$("#wt").val("200");
$("#att").val("100");
$("#wtt").val("200");
$("#gt").val("600");
$("#th").val("42");
```

I have hard coded the values here for an example. I then go to retrieve the values of the hidden fields in my `aspx.cs` file, and they are all null. What am I doing wrong here? Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you view source from a browser, you will probably find the IDs have been thrown away and replaced with generated ones. `runat="server"` causes it to use its own naming system.

Use `ClientIDMode="Static"` so that it will retain your original IDs.

e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" id="at" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('#<%= at.ClientID %>').val("100");
$('#<%= wt.ClientID %>').val("200");
$('#<%= att.ClientID %>').val("100");
$('#<%= wtt.ClientID %>').val("200");
$('#<%= gt.ClientID %>').val("600");
$('#<%= th.ClientID %>').val("42");
```